# ¿Cómo hacer que un EventListener se gatille sólo cuando se agregan documentos?

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo un `EventListener` enlazado a la colección de `Productos` que funciona muy bien.

El `OnEvent` gatilla un `Refresh()` de los documentos en la coleccion, y cada vez que se agrega uno nuevo lo muestra en tiempo real. (Hasta aqui todo bien).

El problema es que también manda a refrescar toda la colección cuando se **edita** un producto (lo que no deberia de pasar para nuestros propositos), como puedo evitar que se gatille cuando se actualiza?

O mejor dicho, cómo puedo dejar el EventListener para que sólo se gatille cuando se agrega un producto nuevo?

EventListener:

```
private void ProductosListener()
        {            
                ListenerProd = database.Collection("Productos").AddSnapshotListener(this);
        }
```

OnEvent:

```
public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
        {
            var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;
                if (data.Metadata.IsFromCache)
                {
                    return;
                }

            Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes evitar que el listener se gatille pero si puedes validar el tipo de evento y ejecutar `Refresh()` sólo si algún documento fue agregado.

Los documentos modificados están en la propiedad `DocumentChanges`. Cada uno de ellos tiene un método `GetType()` que indica el tipo de modificación. Sabiendo eso puedes hacer una validación como esta

```
public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object value, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
{
    var data = (QuerySnapshot)value;
    bool hasNewDocuments = data.DocumentChanges.Any(c => c.GetType() == DocumentChange.Type.Added);
    if (hasNewDocuments && !data.Metadata.IsFromCache)
    {
        Refresh();
    }           
}
```

Para que esto funcione debes incluir la metadata en el listener

```
database.Collection("Productos").AddSnapshotListener(MetadataChanges.Include, this);
```

Comment: Me da error aqui c.Type y dice Document.Change.Type es tipo, lo que no es valido en el contexto indicado.

Comment: Xamarin solo tiene GetType y no Type. Puedes intentar con esto y si te funciona nos avisas, y tu lo puedes editar a tu respuesta @SinneroftheSystem. Codigo: var vType = data.DocumentChanges[i].GetType();
                    if (Convert.ToString(vType) == "ADDED") {..

Comment: @Jorge.Mendez gracias por la corrección. `Any()` tampoco existe?